# How to create dependent dropdowns with Reagent in ClojureScript?

Tags: drop-down-menu, clojurescript, reagent

For example, if you select Toyota in one dropdown, then another dropdown will appear with models of that vehicle. I'd like to be able to add other vehicles as well, so that if Toyota is already selected, then that option won't appear when you select another vehicle type.

Currently, I've tried having a shared Reagent atom between the brand and model dropdowns, which indicates the brand selected. Then a shared Reagent atom between all the dropdowns of the selected brands. However, brand dropdowns don't re-render when a brand becomes selected in another dropdown.

Any ideas for how to implement this with Reagent?

Comment: Can you please post the code of your dropdown components?